# Button inside an iframe is not working

Tags: html, button, iframe

I am using a simple iframe code;

```
<iframe src="http://caesium.x10.mx/test/index.html" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none" width="852" height="500"></iframe>
```

And inside http://caesium.x10.mx/test/index.html there is a working button (bottom right) but if you try to click this button on the iframed page (http://caesium.x10.mx/test/index.php) the button does not work.

Can anyone help me find a solution to this?

Thanks!

The code being used for the button.

```
<center><button onclick="ChangeSkin()">Change Skin</button></center>

<script>
function ChangeSkin() {
    location.href = 'https://www.minecraft.net/profile/skin/remote?url=https://crafatar.com/skins/' + document.getElementById('username').value + '.png';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Update: I've test this on making a blank page with only an iframe code and the button still did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible the entire iframe is behind another transparent layer?

Try setting css properties:

**EDIT:**

Position:static;
z-index: 1000000; (or higher than any other elements)

You can do this either in a linked .css file, or within the head tags of the page like so:

```
    <head>
      <style>
        #content{
          Position:static;
          z-index: 1000000;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
```

I often find this to be the issue when ui elements are not functioning as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: No problem hope you find a solution. I'll take another look in the morning if you don't have an accepted answer by then.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the new css properties are being added to the iframe?

Comment: What do you mean by "added to the iframe"?

Comment: Are they applied to the iFrame element?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Try iframe{position:static !important; z-index:1000000; !important}

Comment: I really think the overlapping elements issue is at the root of your problem!

Comment: Still does not seem to work. I also tried to have a iframe on a blank page, so no coding except for iframe, and it still did not work from there.

Comment: I've just tested on a blank page and it totally does work, can you set up a JSFiddle?

Comment: http://caesium.x10.mx/test/blankpage.html Didn't work for me. I set up a JSFiddle account.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say 'the button does not work', do you mean there is no response from the browser at all?

Comment: The example you just posted works fine for me but links to a blank page.

Comment: Yes. From the original page (http://caesium.x10.mx/test/index.html) the button works perfectly fine, but after iframing it on (http://caesium.x10.mx/test/index.php) it does not work at all.

Comment: I used JSFiddle and added the iframe code (<iframe src="http://caesium.x10.mx/test/index.html" style="border:none" width="852" height="500"></iframe>) and when i click the button there is a loading icon on the tab but nothing happens.

Comment: OK, i finally have a solution for you! The problem is that your entire content div is behind a transparent layer. Please see amended answer.

Comment: Oh thanks! I can click it but sadly its not fully resolved. Now from the iframed page, when i click it i get the same issue as from JSFiddle, a loading icon on tab but nothing happening. I right-clicked the button and "copy address" and I got this link; http://caesium.x10.mx/test/index.php . And from JSFiddle, same thing with copy address, i got https://jsfiddle.net/. It seems to give the link of the page you are on instead of the intended redirect.

Comment: I added what code i am using for the button. Also thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think you now have a completely different issue related to iframe security. Your button is now throwing Refused to display 'https://minecraft.net/en/profile/skin/remote/?url=https://crafatar.com/skins/DrSlaughter0.png' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: Please post a new question related to this new issue.

Comment: Is it setting it to sameorigin because of the web host?

Comment: I am not familiar with this issue but yes it is likely to do with the target rather than your code.

Comment: There may well be a way round it though.

Comment: Thanks, ill try to search for a solution with the more known issue.

Comment: No worries feel free to accept my answer to your original issue :)

Comment: this did fix the issue for android but not iOs

Answer (score 0):

Your transparent footer div is overlapping the iFrame. If I give your content div a positive `z-index` (like `#content { z-index: 1; }`), then the div containing your iFrame is layered on top of the footer, and all the buttons start working again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Iframes are great, but from what I remember the entire Iframe is one button.

Thats because of exploits that broke out a long while back. The Iframe is basically a live updated screenshot.

I have however seen many that allow links.

So, I would try the other answers first.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I actually did search a lot to find a solution and none did work for me thats why I ended up posting here.

Comment: There is a way, however I found out a long time ago that the iframe content needs to be in the server. Hard to explain, basically you can't click the button.because its functionality isn't being found and executed. I never solved this one, just realised it is back-ended iframe looking like its front-ended Unfortutely you can't look into a servers programming logic without being granted access. So the only example I tinkered with I wasn't able to see what was going on in full.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem in bootstrap 4 by adding the following to my custom stylesheet:

```
iframe{
  z-index:9999;
}
```

That seemed to do the trick